# Creating vibrations from an electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, vibration

I am trying to produce vibrations using an electromagnet, with a permanent magnet armature. (Picture below.)

Are the vibrations being produced from the fluctuations in the AC current? Does the electromagnet push and pull the armature to produce the vibrations, or are the vibrations being produced from the armature being suspended within the magnetic flux?

I'm attempting to build this and am unclear of what type of power to apply to it. I would like to control the intensity of the vibrations (assuming through amplitude and not change in frequency or perhaps both.)

Should I use a VFD? PWM? AC? DC?

[image]

Comment: What is the source of that drawing?  What effect are you trying to reproduce?

Comment: From the size of it a 1.5 Hp linear motor like those used in 14" disk drives would be great. or use a smaller motor with a cam or off-center push rod to drive the displacement with variable speed increasing acceleration by 2nd order effects. Power depends on inertial mass and energy to raise table contents.  The base needs a tight neoprene damper but even Lord Mounts have a Q of 5.  It depends if you want constant g, random g or constant x or v or swept tune to resonance.  Where are your specs?  **Never think of a solution before defining the physics of the problem for input and output.**

Comment: Such a system will require AC excitation, and be strongly biased towards a particular oscillating frequency (and modes thereof), defined by the masses and stiffness of constituents.

Comment: A geared motor driving a pushrod would probably give more predictable results as the system would be far less dependent on resonant modes which would in turn be dependent on the mass of the apparatus, 'springiness' of the springs and contents of the 'trough'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a linear vibratory feeder system.

- On each half cycle of the supply the armature (4) will be attracted by the coil (5).
- During the zero-cross of the mains cycle the force of attraction will weaken and the springs will restore the system to its natural position and, since it should be operating close to its resonant frequency, there will most likely be some overshoot.
- Components on the feeder will be thrown in the direction ***F*** and fall back onto the track at some point forward of their original position.
- On the next attraction cycle the parts will tend to stay in their horizontal position due to inertia as the track falls away and backwards.

The simplest solution is to tune the system to vibrate at 100 or 120 Hz for 50 or 60 Hz supply. Then you can use a variac (variable transformer) to drive the coil. Failing that there are vibratory feeder drivers commercially available. These will be rather like a VFD but optimised for this application with features such as single-phase output, soft start, variable output voltage (vibration amplitude) and frequency (to match the mechanical system).

I've worked with such systems and being able to vary the frequency is a huge help. As resonant frequency is approached the track vibration will increase very dramatically and the amplitude will have to be turned down. At resonance very little energy will be required to keep the thing running well.

If you're using low voltage coils then a H-bridge drive fed from a DC supply may do the job. If not and you don't want to purchase a commercial system then you'll be looking at some sort of single-phase inverter.